# Volt regulator for in the car to run a rasperry pi

Tags: power-supply, pcb, raspberry-pi, schematics

So I have an raspberry pi (with alot of other stuff on it like a touchscreen and GPs module), but I use it in the car. It consumes alot of power and the default power supply which deliveres 2.4 amps isn't enough. So I was wondering if it is possible to make a power converter that converts 12V (10 amp) from the car, to 5V (high as possible amps) to run the pi. Now, Will this damage the pi? Or will the pi only take what it needs?

Now I have an schema, but I have no clue if the schema is correct, so here it is;

[image: schema]

Also, I want to make a PC out of it, so here is that result:

[image: pcb]

If someone could help me out with this, that would be awesome!

I'm using eagle as drawing software. Could someone please help me?

Regards,

Robin

Comment: You won't find a 4700uF capacitor rated for 24V~35V on that size. Doesn't you board have input-output connections? Holes for mounting? Also, why traces so thin? You probably won't be able to draw more than 0.5A from SOT223 LM317, especially at that voltage drop.

Comment: Well, I have no idea of electronics, could you maybe help me?

Comment: For 0.5 A and higher you **really** should not be using linear regulators like this as these "burn" energy to lower the voltage. You need massive cooling for that, that's very impractical. What you want is a **switched mode** DCDC converter. Something like this module: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/5A-MPPT-Solar-Panel-Controller-Step-down-Constant-Current-Voltage-Power-Module-/131572469757?hash=item1ea2548ffd:g:DMIAAOSwT6pVrMli

Comment: Be aware of load-dumps, which can yield a peak of \$120\:\textrm{V}\$ for some hundreds of milliseconds of time. It may be clamped to a smaller value in the car. But you can't count on it. It's not likely to happen with the battery in place. But it can happen if someone unscrews the connectors and removes one of them while the car is running. And that does happen, sometimes. I know I've done it before.

Comment: Hmm... well I don't know, how should it look like then? Since I'm kinda in need of a high current power supply to use in the car (not connected to the battery but like the car chargers to charge the phone). How can I acheve this?

Comment: You should use a switch-mode DC-DC converter rather than a linear regulator like the LM317. The maximum rated current for the 317 is only 1 Amp, I think (maybe 1.5) so won't do in any case. On your schematic, you need a resistor between the LM317 ADJ terminal and Ground to set the output voltage. C3 isn't connected to ground.  Your input wire and output wire apparently have the same net name so they are connected together on the PCB.

Comment: I cannot stress enough that you really should be using a switched more DC DC (step down) converter instead of an LM317 or any other linear regulator. Use a lin. regulator and I **guarantee** you that it will **overheat**. Also designing a DCDC converter on a PCB is not for beginners, get a cheap Chinese module instead. Designing your own without guidance from someone with experience will end in a non-working circuit. I guarantee it.

Comment: Oh also just noticed that your schematic will not give out 5 V but about 1.25 V. That's because you grounded the ADJ pin instead of connecting it to ground via a resistor (see the datasheet). Also you've choosen the SMD version of the LM317, you cannot attach a proper heatsink to it. So it **will** overheat unless you draw less than 0.1 A from it.

Answer (score 5):

If you plan to use a LM317 (according to the schematic) it will fry in a second. As you can see on the datasheet, it's recommended to not draw over 1.5Amp.

[image]

So this chip doesn't fit your need.

If the system draw more than 5A, you will face some heat problem if you use linear regulator. Hopefully, there is an alternative : Switching power supply / regulator. These king of regulator are a way more efficient (except for low current consomption) than linear regulator. It's also harder to design but you will find a lot of topic here on EE.

---

*Edit*

Once you will have acquire some knowledge about switch regulator, you can take a look at [TI power supply website](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulator-overview.page). It's a pretty easy way to design what you need.

I'm sure other manufacturer provide same interface, but this one is very clear. (especially for a EE beginner)

Comment: I see, but if I try to find a good module, I can't find any? Could someone create a component list and/or a schema?

Comment: @Robin You can find enough information here to make it yourself.. Use the link I gave in the post, it's very useful ;)

Comment: Aha, I found a component (the LM3481), which can give me 10 amps (I guess?) But now I can't find it in all of my libs in Eagle... :/ Or how to use it... Anyow, I'll see what I can figure out :)

Comment: @Robin It's just a controller. Did you read about switch regulator? It's not that easy. Especially for a beginner ! For footprint, use SnapEda.

Comment: @Robin: Judging from your LM317 schematic and PC board, I strongly suggest that you buy a ready-made DC-DC converter rather than try to build your own.

Comment: I have found some on aliexpress, those can convert 24-12v to 5v 10amp

Comment: Search for a car plug USB charger, they are at least intended for use in a car environment. I saw some up to 3A. Do you realy need 10A to power a Pi?